# iOS 9 … Are embedded WebView(s) exempt from the App Transport Security (ATS) rules that block insecure HTTP hosts?

Tags: ios, webview, appcelerator

[Apple will require HTTPS connections for iOS apps by the end of 2016.](https://techcrunch.com/2016/06/14/apple-will-require-https-connections-for-ios-apps-by-the-end-of-2016/) How will this effect the Titanium.UI.createWebView method or  Alloy element to create a web view. Will these methods throw errors if the url they are referencing is not switched to HTTPS?

Comment: There's a `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` key added in iOS 10 that you can use to allow web views to load http content

Comment: Also, you are still allowed to turn of ATS but you need to have a valid  reason